# Play Framework 2.6: Configure Akka HTTP Logging

Tags: scala, playframework, logback

I have a Play 2.6 application where I let the application log everything to a log file and to the terminal during development. I want all output which is visible on the terminal to be in the log file as well. Occasionally I get messages like this:

```
[WARN] [04/26/2018 20:06:22.108] [play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(play-dev-mode)] Illegal request, responding with status '501 Not Implemented': Unsupported HTTP method: COPY
```

However I am not able to direct these (I guess Akku logs) to my app.log file. Can anybody help? Here is my logback.xml:

```
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />
   
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/app.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>[%date]: %message%n%xException</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNCFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNCSTDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </appender>


  <logger name="access" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCFILE" />
  </logger>

  <!-- Off these ones as they are annoying, and anyway we manage configuration ourselves -->
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCFILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCSTDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```